# How to display date in Julian in the mode line?

Tags: mode-line, time-date, calendar

The following setting display the date in Gregorian calendar in the mode line.

```
(setq display-time-day-and-date t)
(display-time)
```

My question is how to change the above settings for date to be shown in the Julian calendar?

Comment: Does the `display-time-format` variable help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute arbitrary date strings by overriding `display-time-string-forms`.

The documentation says this:

> List of expressions governing display of the time in the mode line.
>   For most purposes, you can control the time format using
>   `display-time-format' which is a more standard interface.
>
> This expression is a list of expressions that can involve the keywords
>   `load`, `day`, `month`, and `year`, `12-hours`, `24-hours`, `minutes`,
>   `seconds`, all numbers in string form, and `monthname`, `dayname`,
>   `am-pm`, and `time-zone` all alphabetic strings, and `mail` a true/nil
>   value.
>
> For example, the form
>
> ```
> '((substring year -2) "/" month "/" day
>   " " 24-hours ":" minutes ":" seconds
>   (if time-zone " (") time-zone (if time-zone ")")
>   (if mail " Mail" ""))
> ```
>
> would give mode line times like `94/12/30 21:07:48 (UTC)'.

To display the Julian date as provided by `calendar` try this:

```
(require 'calendar)
(setq display-time-string-forms
      '((calendar-julian-date-string)))
(display-time)
```

Comment: by Julian date, I mean the default Julian date of Emacs. That can be given by `M-x calendar` then `M-x calendar-julian-print-date`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Julian dates, but please see my updated answer.  You can use `display-time-string-forms` to call `calendar-julian-date-string` on the Gregorian date.

Comment: Thank you. `(require 'calendar)` should be added. By the way what is the value `now`. When restarting Emacs, the displaying time becomes different. I think without `now` it would be fine.

Comment: `now` has the value of evaluating `(current-time)`.